# Aptana opens and then immediately closes

Tags: aptana3

I have Aptana Studio 3 installed on Windows 7 64bit and have tried opening it for the first time, but it loads the workbench and actually opens, but then after about a second it closes.  No error or warning.  Our C drives are locked down, so I've taken some advice from another post to point the workspace somewhere readable, but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, was a solution to this ever found?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  This issue is still persisting and I've had to switch to other software.